# Read NetCDF variable of type VLEN, C interface

Tags: python, c++, c, arrays, netcdf

I am looking for some example code showing how I would read a Variable Length Array from a NetCDF 4 file using the C interface.

I have a file that I have created using the python `netCDF4` library:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

def make_fire_dataset(fname, sizey=10, sizex=10):
    ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(fname, mode='w', format='NETCDF4')

    Y = ncfile.createDimension('Y', sizey)
    X = ncfile.createDimension('X', sizex)

    fire_year_vector = ncfile.createVLType(np.int, 'fire_year_vector')
    fire_years = ncfile.createVariable('fire_years', fire_year_vector, ('Y','X'))

    fire_sizes = ncfile.createVariable('fire_sizes', fire_year_vector, ('Y','X'))

    yr_data = np.empty(sizey * sizex, object)
    sz_data = np.empty(sizey * sizex, object)

    # for every (y,x) pixel, make a pair of vectors.
    # one vector holds the year of fire, the other vector holds
    # a number for the size, or severity of fire 
    for n in range(sizey * sizex):
        yr_data[n] = np.array(sorted(np.random.randint(1900, 2006, np.random.randint(0,10,1))), dtype=np.int)
        sz_data[n] = np.random.randint(0,100,len(yr_data[n]))


    yr_data = np.reshape(yr_data,(sizey,sizex))
    sz_data = np.reshape(sz_data,(sizey,sizex))

    fire_years[:] = yr_data
    fire_sizes[:] = sz_data

    ncfile.close()   


# Create the new fire file...
make_fire_dataset("new-fire-dataset.nc", sizey=10, sizex=10)
```

Checkout the file with `ncdump`:

```
$ ncdump -h new-fire-dataset.nc 
netcdf new-fire-dataset {
types:
  int64(*) fire_year_vector ;
dimensions:
    Y = 10 ;
    X = 10 ;
variables:
    fire_year_vector fire_years(Y, X) ;
    fire_year_vector fire_sizes(Y, X) ;
}
```

So each (Y,X) "pixel" in the 10x10 grid has two variable-length `fire_year_vector`s associated with the pixel.

Now I'd like to read the fire_years array and fire_sizes array for a single (Y,X) point into containers in my C++ program. I have read the documentation here: https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-c/Variable-Length-Array.html#Variable-Length-Array several times, but I don't quite understand how I should go about the operation.

For a variety of reasons, I'd like to stick with the C interface, even though my main program is C++. Ideally the data I read from the netcdf file will populate an STL container somewhere in the scope of my program, but if it takes a little bit of C-style code to get there, that is fine.